# Importing testcafe project to intellij

Tags: javascript, testing, intellij-idea, automated-tests, testcafe

When importing a testcafe project to intellij, the "node" folder does not get added. I have to copy it manually and put it in the project, though i have node and testcafe installed[image] locally. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: what is `node` folder, why do you expect it to be added when opening the project in IDEA? And how do you import your existing project in it, BTW?

Comment: its basically node modules and npm. I am cloning the project via git. Without the node folder none of my tests execute

Comment: and what is the result of cloning the same project in terminal with `git clone`?

Comment: its the same.I have a similar project when i import..it will include the node folder automatically. But that doesnt happen with the other project. i need to manually move the node folde

Comment: looks like this folder is not a part of your git repo, as it's not created when cloning it; anyway, it's not a problem with Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node/` and `node_modules/` are usually excluded (if it's set up correctly) in `.gitignore`. The reason for that is they contain a lot of data that you just don't want to put under versioning because they are not your project (actual tests, helpers, test data etc.), they are just your "infrastructure" for your tests.

Your flow should look more like this:

1. getting the project by cloning it with `git clone`
2. installing `node` if it's not installed already
3. installing `npm` if it's not installed already
4. installing all node modules you need for your project, including `testcafe`

   - you can do this globally, or locally as described in [docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/install-testcafe.html)
   - if your project already has `package.json` file, you can install all depenndencies for your project with npm: `$ npm install`, it's described [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Comment: I am following the above steps. But for some reason, i am not seeing the node folder due to which I copy and paste in the project

Comment: If you can use node, you don't need that folder in your project dir. It could be installed globally.